# Average power and power density in microscopy

Tags: laser, microscopy

In a microscopy experiment, usually the power density at sample  is reported like XX MW/cm^2 . Is this the power at the objective focal spot. Can it be calculated if we have the info like objective numerical aperture and average power of the incident wavelength?

Comment: Are you sure you are measuring megawatts (MW) and not milliwatts (mW)?

Comment: Pretty sure that power densities are calculated using the measured average powers which are in milliwatts. Dont know how this calculation is performed though. Also, kW to MW are pretty common power densities in super resolution microscopies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the power at the objective focal spot. Can it be calculated if we have the info like objective numerical aperture and average power of the incident wavelength?

Yes, usually $J$ in $[W/m^2]$ gives the energy per unit time that crosses a unit area at the focal plane. Its value depends on how your (laser) light is prepared, and on the transmission of the objective (which can be quite low).

If you focus the light on a confocal spot (having collimated light at the back focal plane of the objective), you'll have all the energy in the PSF of the microscope, so if you calculate/measure the PSF you can determine $J$.

In epi-illumination (laser focused at the back focal plane of the objective), you have a collimated beam, but never perfectly collimated, at the focsal plane. So in this case to get $J$ you have to determine the magnification of what is effectively a telescope (focusing lens + objective).

In all cases, when possible, the best is to measure the surface $A$ illuminated at the focal plane (eg by a camera), the light power $P$ in $[W]$ right before the objective, and the transmission of the objective $T$.

Then $J=P/(AT)$